# ¿cómo filtrar columnas y sumar en pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con las siguientes columnas
asesor: son varios, tienda: son varias por cada asesor, y puntos: 0 y 1

lo que necesito es por cada asesor y por cada tienda sumar los 1 en la columna puntos.

por ejemplo

```
asesor  tienda puntos
A1      t1      1
A1      t2      0
A1      t2      1
A1      t3      1
A1      t3      1
A2      t1      0
A2      t2      1
A3      t4      1
A3      t4      1
```

Al fina debo tener una tabla del asesor y de la tienda con la suma de puntos

```
A1  t1  1
A1  t2  1
A1  t3  2
A2  t1  0
A2  t2  1
A3  t4  2
```

Con este código filtro al asesor y a la tienda, pero no logro hacer la suma

```
w = t2['Nombre Asesor'] == 'A1'
x = t2['TIENDA'] == 'T1'
np.sum(t2[w & x]['Obligatoria'])
```

Esto me resulta en una serie con la suma de los asesores y la tienda, además el número en puntos no me corresponde con lo que debe generar por ejmplo dice 50 pero en realidad son 20.

```
A1A1A1
T1T1T1
50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a envocarme en lo que entiendo es lo fundamental de tu pregunta:

> lo que necesito es por cada asesor y por cada tienda sumar los 1 en la
>   columna puntos.

En primer lugar creamos un ejemplo con la información de tu pregunta:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

test_data=StringIO("""asesor;tienda;puntos
A1;t1;1
A1;t2;0
A1;t2;1
A1;t3;1
A1;t3;1
A2;t1;0
A2;t2;1
A3;t4;1
A3;t4;1""")

df = pd.read_csv(test_data, sep=";")
```

Vamos a usare el [`group_by()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) y la función [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum) para llegar a lo que buscas:

```
g = df.groupby(['asesor', 'tienda'])['puntos'].sum()
print(g)

asesor  tienda
A1      t1        1
        t2        1
        t3        2
A2      t1        0
        t2        1
A3      t4        2
Name: puntos, dtype: int64
```

Como vemos, armamos grupos por asesor/tienda y conseguimos sumarizar los puntos de cada grupo. También podemos transformar la salida en un `Dataframe` tradicional, mediante [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index):

```
print(g.reset_index())

  asesor tienda  puntos
0     A1     t1       1
1     A1     t2       1
2     A1     t3       2
3     A2     t1       0
4     A2     t2       1
5     A3     t4       2
```